# Expiring cookies in native NodeJS

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, cookies

I'm trying to expire a cookie with native NodeJS, specifically for the chrome browser. However, the expiration date that I place doesn't cause the cookie to go away.

As of right now, here's my code:

```
var cookie = 'Expires=' + new Date();
response.setHeader('Set-Cookie', cookie);
```

I ended up getting cookies with the expiration date like so even after subsequent requests:

```
cookie: Expires=Wed Mar 22 2017 02:14:52 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This, It may work for you.

`'Set-Cookie':'sesh=wakadoo; expires='+new Date(new Date().getTime()+86409000).toUTCString();`

Replace **sesh=wakadoo** with your variable.

Comment: I see now. The rest of the cookie needs to match, otherwise it thinks you're sending a completely new cookie. However, since I need to make it expire immediately. I removed the extra time from the code, and used this instead: `var cookie = username=artekis; expires='+new Date().toUTCString();`

Answer (score 0):

You can set cookie expires and httpOnly using the below code.

```
res.cookie(myCookie, myValue, { expires: new Date(Date.now()+10000), httpOnly: true };
```

https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.cookie